# Unable to fit background image fit inside another image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking at this site I've noticed that the background image that displays the page bleeds out of the sides of the monitor. Is there a way to fix this?

img src="img/laptop.png" id="laptop" class="tour" alt="laptop" />

The laptop is a png with a transparent center. I was then apply a class to the laptop which would apply a background image behind the laptop. ie

.tour { background: url("../img/tour.jpg") center top no-repeat; }

The problem occurs when some of the images are larger than the width of the laptop

Comment: what do you mean by bleeds out. It seems to be okay. What do you want to be it. Give more details

Comment: I hope you ain't promoting a website this way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to make the background of the image of the laptop white, which would then cover up the part of the image which 'bleeds out'.

Another quick solution would be to resize all the background images so that they fit properly within the monitor.

I think the way to do it properly is to have an absolutely positioned element which fits within the bounds of the laptop screen and shows the image.

Something along the lines of

```
<div class='image-container' style='position: relative;'>
    <div id='background' style='position: absolute; left: 100px; right: 100px; top: 30px; bottom: 120px;></div>
    <img src='img/laptop.png' />
</div>
```

This would need some proper measurement/testing of the actual margins on the image, and would need changes to the javascript and css to work/look right.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I also updated the question so it is hopefully a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a width for the "container clearfix" class, and then add an appropriate width, say about 920px to the monitor, so that it's size is more appropriate to cover the photos you're using.